# How can I stop WP from automatically marking "Automatically close comments on articles older than 28 days"?

Tags: comments

Every few days my WP automatically marks "Automatically close comments on articles older than 28 days"

I don't want this! I want to keep my comments open forever. How can I stop WP from marking this option every 4 days?! I don't know why it's doing this.

Thank you so much!

Comment: WP most certainly doesn’t automatically change this (or any other) native option by itself. _Something_ that is not WP core is doing that. Unfortunately hard to guess why. You might try inquiring with your hosting support if they run anything special for WP, review plugins you use, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the preference from settings.

Navigate to Settings > Discussion page on your wp-admin

Find **Automatically close comments on articles older than**
and uncheck that option.

[image: Screenshot]

That should solve your problem.